# How to get width and height of a .pdf file with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to obtain only the dimensions (height and width in "mm") of a file, for example .pdf with JS before sending it to the server?

Comment: No, unless you parse it manually using JavaScript. There's no Web API for handling PDF files.

Comment: You could open the PDF document with Mozilla's pdf.js viewer, which will give you the viewport dimensions of a page. https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/index.html#interactive-examples